# Numerical Integration with Green's Function

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, singularity, greens-function

I'm trying to solve the 1D heat equation on a semi-infinite domain with no heat sources and inhomogeneous boundary conditions:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}$$
$$T(0,t)=\phi(t)$$
$$T(x\rightarrow\infty,t) = T_i$$
$$T(x,0)=T_i$$

for which the Green's Function is:

$$G(x,t|x',\tau)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha(t-\tau)}}\left(e^{-\frac{(x-x')^2}{4\alpha(t-\tau)}}-e^{-\frac{(x+x')^2}{4\alpha(t-\tau)}}\right)$$

My questions are:

1. When writing the solution:
   $$T(x,t)=\int_{x'=0}^{\infty}\left.G(x,t|x',\tau)\right|_{\tau=0}T_idx'+\alpha\int_{\tau=0}^{t}\left.\frac{\partial G}{\partial x'}\right|_{x'=0}\phi(\tau)d\tau$$
   why is the boundary condition, $\phi(t)$, not recovered when $x=0$?
2. When numerically evaluating:
   $$\alpha\int_{\tau=0}^t\left.\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial x'}\right|_{x'=0,x=0}\phi(\tau)d\tau$$
   where
   $$\alpha\left.\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial x'}\right|_{x'=0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4\alpha(t-\tau)}}\left((t-\tau)^{-3/2}-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha}(t-\tau)^{-5/2}\right)$$
   what happens when $t=\tau$ at $x=0$? Performing the integral just gives $\infty$ for all time. I imagine the integration as a convolution of $\phi(t)$ with $1/t$.
3. Can this be solved by splitting $T(x,t)=U(x,t)+V(x,t)$ where $U$ satisfies the inhomogeneous BCs and $V$ satisfies the inhomogeneous BCs? If so, does the form of $V(x,t)$ matter? Working it through requires evaluation of $\dot{\phi}(t)$? Or am I just completely wrong on all counts?

Comment: Are you sure the boundary condition as $\lim_{x \to \infty}T(x,t) = f(\color{red}x)$?

Comment: The original question is posed as $f(x)=T_i$, i.e. an isothermal semi-infinite body, which can also be zero. In which case the notation is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}T(x,t) = T_i$. I just thought I'd like to extend it to a case where the initial temperature was non-uniform. Whether this is the correct way to state it, I'm not sure. Logically a body with a non-uniform temperature distribution must have non-zero heat flux so that the temperature even at infinity must be varying over time.

Comment: I should have probably just used $f(x)=0$, but I don't think this has an effect on recovering the BC and what to do with numerical integration at $x=0$ and $t=\tau$.

Comment: The initial temperature being non-uniform is given by the condition $T(x,0) = f(x)$, where $f$ is non-constant. The notation $\lim_{x \to \infty} T(x,t) = T_{i}$ where $T_{i}$ is a constant or function of $t$ is fine. If $T_{i}$ is a function of $x$, as you have it stated, then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'll edit the question accordingly to replace $f(x)$ with $T_i$. But as an add-on, what is the semi-infinite condition for a body with non-uniform initial temperature?

Comment: For physical reasons, you would want the solution to be bounded as $x \to \infty$, so something like $\lim_{x \to \infty} T(x,t) = 0$ would seem to be the most appropriate.